# Why ECDSA verification fails in Android using Spongy Castle?

Tags: android, signature, verification, ecdsa, spongycastle

I am trying to verify a signature in Android using spongy castle. This dependency has been added to gradle as:

```
implementation group: 'com.madgag.spongycastle', name: 'bcpkix-jdk15on', version: '1.58.0.0'
```

When running below code in Android Flamingo I always get *false* for *verified* with different public keys, and signatures. But all of them are valid and verified according to [this](http://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/sample/sample-ecdsa.html) site. Here is my Android code (I need to use `secp256k1` and hex values for key, message, and signature):

```
String publicKeyHex = "04954ed5969f7d4cc2baa1f0345f037a4758e84058d202feb64885c32dfc62123af4c8ccfba16088fc9cc2bd84594d810ad470706cfddfc17999d291b038f4c9f1";
String messageHex   = "12ca8b3b17607820279c7e0095d655d9ce289e90cccc0e99ae00f5e29f8d6615";
String signatureHex = "3045022100affcf495d11d02fcde6f9cd502975b78dd18b4b50127edef56683ca8534575cf02206f3d92bb26d515d122754c88e92c1d7d8bfc2b35876608b9c75ee9cbcd6fdde9";

byte[] publicKeyBytes = hexStringToByteArray(publicKeyHex);
byte[] messageBytes   = hexStringToByteArray(messageHex);
byte[] signatureBytes = hexStringToByteArray(signatureHex);

final ECNamedCurveParameterSpec spec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256k1");
final ECNamedCurveSpec params = new ECNamedCurveSpec("secp256k1", spec.getCurve(), spec.getG(),spec.getN());

KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
ECPoint ecPoint = ECPointUtil.decodePoint(params.getCurve(), publicKeyBytes);
ECPublicKeySpec pubKeySpec = new ECPublicKeySpec(ecPoint, params);
ECPublicKey publicKey = (ECPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);

Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("Sha256withECDSA");
signature.initVerify(publicKey);
signature.update(messageBytes);
boolean verified = signature.verify(signatureBytes);
```

and this is the definition of `hexStringToByteArray` method:

```
public static final byte[] hexStringToByteArray(final String str) {
    int len = str.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2)
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(str.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(str.charAt(i+1), 16));
    return data;
}
```

what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verification is successful if the ASCII (or UTF-8) encoding of `messageHex` is applied and not the hex decoded `messageHex`, i.e. with

```java
byte[] messageBytes = messageHex.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
```

verification is successful.

This means that the ASCII encoding and not the hex decoding of `messageHex` was signed.